# GridView hyperLinkField value to passing to textbox on different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the below hyperLinkField that I was to pass a value into a textbox onto a different page.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="PropertySearch_GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Height ="1px" Width ="300px"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="True" >
            <Columns>



                <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Horizon_Property_Id" DataNavigateUrlFields="Horizon_Property_Id" HeaderText="Horizon_Property_Id"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/CreateSurvey.aspx?Create_Prop_ID.text={0}" SortExpression="Horizon_Property_Id" 
                />
```

when I run the app and press the hyperlink, the CreateSurvey page opens, but the Create_Prop_ID textbox does not populate.

could someone help please.

Regards

Rob

Comment: The alternate is to use a session to store and access on different pages.

Comment: My first method was using session but I also want to filter and sort, and that makes the select hyperlink become out of sync,

see below post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817664/c-sharp-gridview-refresh-index-after-applying-filter

Comment: No session I found there.

Comment: I am using session I just haven't put it on my post, the problem I have is the Select link is not in sync when I filter or sort.

Comment: With the HyperLinkField I am using within my gridview, am I missing anything for the value to pass to the textbox correctly?

Comment: that only you can find what is missing in your project.

Comment: sorry that didn't make sense,